# RegExp gives unexpected result when tested against `undefined`

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building a **password strength** validator that check whether password contains lower-case and upper-case characters. I use regular expressions for that and get unexpected results when provided password string is **undefined** - see screenshot below. I would expect both checks to return **false**, yet the first one returns **true**.

Why does the first check return **true**?
[image]

Comment: maybe you are passing "undefined" as a string, rather than an actual undefined value? It is unfortunately not possible to tell this from your screenshot, but it would explain the output.

Comment: @MFreidank you can clearly see what is passed to test() in the screenshot - nothing

Comment: [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/) may help you out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript will attempt to convert the argument of `test` to a string if it's not one. So since:

```
String(undefined) === "undefined"
```

Your first regex is true since `"undefined"` contains one or more lowercase letters. The second is false since there are no uppercase letters.

You can even verify this by noting that

```
/^undefined$/.test()
```

returns `true`.